# TIBCO SPOTFIRE : Redirect Dependent Elements

Tags: datasource, spotfire, tibco

I'm searching for a way to switch from a **test** to a **prod1, prod2** and **prod3** environments having same structure, but the schemas have different names.
Is it possible to do it with the same analysis that will be opened later  with a Spotfire web clients (Dedicated for each environments )

I found this in the Doc, but as i said i need something configurable depending on the environment

[image]

***EDIT***

DATASource name : DbParc,
username : DB_PARC2.
So for example when using this analysis in an env with username DB_3, the information link or Procedure element  will still use DB_PARC2

[image]

Thanks 4 any Advices..

Comment: Do you ask here about the promotion of the dashboard between environments which are implemented thu the folders with different naming and access rights ?

Comment: Yes.. Because once i change the username my Datasource.. i got error in the infomations link..

Comment: @JacekSierajewski QST Edited..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dashboard (dxp) that has its own set of Information Links and its own set of datasources objects. You need to have all those objects in one folder.

Then you can use Library Administration tool and take Copy action.

You pick the destination and confirm Copy action.

The newly created folder will contain newly created dashboard and what is essential, the dashboad and its Info Links and column objects etc (all depenedcies of the dashboard) will be connectd to the newly created/copied data sources. Now you can change the datasource specific information as per your needs.

Comment: Changing datasource infomation didnt change the username in the information link column path or procedure element ( capture in edit bloc ) even if in my datasouce information i specified different unsernames

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the (SOAP) Web Services API: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.14.0/doc/api/TIB_sfire_server_WebServices_API_Reference/index.html

There is also an Automation Services task that might be useful: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire_autsvcs/7.14.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_autsvcs_7.14.0_UserGuide/GUID-A7A5FC46-2DC1-4E70-81F4-B34476AE9221.html